# Input clear button does not work in Microsoft Edge

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, redux-form, semantic-ui-react

I am using reactjs, redux form and semantic UI react to build an application. The following codes behavior differently in IE11, Edge, and Chrome. I have included polyfill in the index.js

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
```

In IE11, the input will be rendered with a clear button, and it works well.

In Chrome, the input does not have a clear button.

In edge, the input has a clear button, but it cannot clear the input after clicked.

I have created a demo project for this issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-form-field-level-validation-zedcu?fontsize=14

Can anyone tell me why it does not work in edge? Help is appreciated.

```
import React from "react";
import { Field } from "redux-form";
import { Form } from "semantic-ui-react";
import RenderFieldInput from "../../formElements/Input";
import RenderFieldSelect from "../../formElements/Select";
import { YES_NO } from "../../formElements/SelectOptions";
import { required, email } from "redux-form-validators";
import { createNumberMask, createTextMask } from 'redux-form-input-masks';

const currencyMask = createNumberMask({
  prefix: '$ ',
  suffix: '',
  decimalPlaces: 2,
  locale: 'en-US',
})

const BorrAttributes = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form.Group widths="equal">
        <Field
          name="email"
          component={RenderFieldInput}
          label="Email"
          required="Y"
          validate={[required(), email()]}
        />
        <Field
          name="secondEmail"
          component={RenderFieldInput}
          label="Second Email"
          validate={[email()]}
        />
      </Form.Group>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BorrAttributes;

import React from "react";
import { Form, Popup } from "semantic-ui-react";
import Tooltip from "./Tooltip";

const RenderFieldInput = ({
  input,
  label,
  placeholder,
  required,
  meta: { touched, error, warning }
}) => (
  <Popup
    trigger={
      <Form.Input
        {...input}
        label={label}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        error={error ? true : null}
        required={required === "Y" ? true : null}
        fluid
      />
    }
  >
    <Tooltip touched={touched} error={error} warning={warning} />
  </Popup>
);

export default RenderFieldInput;
```

Comment: I have checked the [Semantic UI samples](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/) and [the redux-form samples](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/gettingstarted.md/), the input fields work well in Microsoft Edge browser (44 version), please check it on your machine. If still not working, please check your Microsoft Edge browser version and try to upgrade the version. If they are works well, perhaps the issue is related to your code, Can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT, please check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-form-field-level-validation-zedcu?fontsize=14. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue for Microsoft Edge https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/17584515/

Comment: Hi Alexey, thanks for your reply. If I use plain javascript, the clear button do work in the Edge.  But not work in the way I did.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the "RenderFieldInput" component, perhaps it is related to the Popup, I think you could feedback this issue to [Semantic-UI-React forum](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues).

As a temporary workaround, you could try to remove this component. Code as below:

```
const FieldLevelValidationForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field
        name="username"
        type="text"
        component="input"
        validate={[required()]}
        label="Username"
      />
    </form>
  );
};
```

More details about semantic UI react  Popup, you could check [this link](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/popup/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is related to the popup.